# Wrap text selection in brackets in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to select some text in a Mathematica notebook and then wrap the selection in brackets?

For example, if I typed the following in a notebook:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

I want to be able to select all the text and then type the command to insert matching curly brackets (`alt-}` on linux) and it would wrap the selection in curly brackets.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function adds a command that basically does what you asked.

As written, it coopts the Control+U key combination, (which is usually 'underline').  You can change that quite simply.  It also adds an item called 'Make List' to the Insert menu, but I imagine you'd just use the key combination.

This modification only persists for the current session, but you could add the function to an init file to load at start-up.  There are other ways of permanently adding the functionality, such as by editing the KeyEventsTranslations file, like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6227/363).)

Once you have run the implementation function it can be executed with Control+U.

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["Make List",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     nb = SelectedNotebook[];
     sel = NotebookRead[nb];
     NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"{", sel, "}"}]]]]],
    MenuKey["u", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Having typed and selected:  1, 2, 3, 4

Control+U

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

**Addendum**

Here is a version you could use instead of your MenuSetup modification.  It's set to activate on "{" key press, and will wrap a selection or just match braces.  Putting this into MenuSetup isn't so straightforward; I would do it by calling an external program from MenuSetup with `KernelExecute`.  It would be just as effective to put the code below in an init file.

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter, MenuItem["Make List",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     nb = SelectedNotebook[];
     sel = NotebookRead[nb];
     If[sel === {},
      FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["InsertMatchingBraces"]],
      NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"{", sel, "}"}]]]]]],
    MenuKey["{", Modifiers -> {}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Comment: Wow that's nice. To be honest I was skeptical that it was even possible.

Comment: I have `MenuItem["Matching {}", "InsertMatchingBraces", MenuKey["{", Modifiers->{}]]` in my `MenuSetup.tr` file so that typing a '{' automatically is paired. Now I want to take your answer and make it so that if there's no selection it just prints matching brackets, but if there is, it wraps the selection.